# Serve different versions of files based on user's browser version

Tags: jquery, python, flask

The frontend of my app is designed to work with very old browsers.  I want to upgrade to Bootstrap 3 and JQuery 2, but I don't want to stop supporting the old browsers.  How can I serve the old version or the new version depending on the user's browser?  Should I do this?  Do I basically need 2 versions of every script, template, and view?

Comment: That sounds like a maintenance nightmare. You'll end up maintaining two (or more) versions of your app.

Comment: One comment; in general, browser detection is strongly avoided. However, feature detection is fine; [Modernizr.js](https://modernizr.com/) may help.

Comment: P.S. I don't *exactly* agree with @FilipDupanović, in terms of dropping support for legacy browsers, but first and foremost work with the latest releases of current browsers, and then go back to improve backwards compatibility... and know that the more sophisticated of what you are running, the less of even a possibility of getting it to work in an older browser. Internet Explorer 6 is called "Internet Exploder 6" for a reason (actually, *many* reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).  With requirejs you should be able to write some logic which serves a different version of the file depending on the browser

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you defer support for legacy browsers and develop against forward-facing engines. The reason is that you may spend 3 weeks adding support for a version of IE that is going to get deprecated a few months later. There goes the added effort!

You should be able to run your build tools against the same dependencies, with different versions.

If your using `npm`, then you can simply distribute two different `package.json` files, `edge.json`, `legacy.json`, then symlink, install dependencies and build the appropriate static assets separately.

Dirty example:

```
git clone --reference app edge
git clone --reference app legacy

ln -s edge/edge.json edge/package.json
ln -s legacy/legacy.json legacy/package.json
```

Now, in Flask, you'll have to sniff the user agent, resolve whether it is an edge or legacy browser and then return an HTML document which will reference assets from the appropriate root. You should then set `Vary: User-Agent` in your response headers.